# GeoJSON coordinates transformation to Web Mercator coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, geojson, mercator

I'm not sure how OpenLayers is converting the raw coordinates from a GeoJSON's `geometry.coordinates` property into a Feature's `extent` property. I can't really seem to find a lot of documentation on it either, does anyone understand what's going on to make this transformation?

Comment: Definition of extent in OL says: `[minx, miny, maxx, maxy]`, see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_extent.html#~Extent. As for coordinate transformation, see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_format_GeoJSON.html

Comment: I'm interested in the transformation, could you elaborate a bit on that please?

Comment: What is not clear in documentation? Or are you interested in the algorithm ot transformation? In the later case question is not OL related.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm interested in the algorithm. Do you know where I can find it?

Comment: You can start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection#Mathematics

Comment: OpenLayers features do not have an extent property - use `feature.getGeometry().getExtent()`  If you transform the geometry to a different projection the extent will be the bounding box of the coordinates in that projection, which in the case of non-parallel projections may be different to transforming the original extent.

Comment: Interesting. Looks like I have my work cut out for me. Is there an external library which can do all these calculations in C#?

Comment: Have a look at https://www.codeproject.com/tips/1072197/coordinate-transformation-using-proj-in-net

Answer (score 1):

For Java and JavaScript I use ports of [PROJ](https://proj.org/), being [Proj4J](https://trac.osgeo.org/proj4j/) and [Proj4js](http://proj4js.org/). According to [language bindings](https://proj.org/development/bindings.html) there is a [PROJ VB Wrappers](http://ftp.dfg.ca.gov/Public/BDB/Tools/proj4/proj_api.zip), which is also mentioned in [C# Library for converting Shapefile Projection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9936256/8957103) question on StackOverflow, but the server seems down.

Maybe [ProjNet (for GeoAPI)](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/ProjNet4GeoAPI/) suits your needs. From personal experience I know that the Java and JavaScript ports can do coordinate transformations for Web Mercator projections. According to the [ReadMe](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/ProjNet4GeoAPI/blob/develop/README.md) ProjNet4GeoAPI supports Mercator and Transverse Mercator.